# Get result when Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS closes

Tags: android

My application checks if GPS enabled and if not it asking user to enable it. 
To lounch settings activity I  use following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

But I need to enable or disable some controls on my activity depending on GPS status. I wonder how I can get result after user closes settings activity. Or maybe it's possible to wait until settings activity closed and then check GPS status again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can check if GPS is enabled in your `onResume()`.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if(!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        // GPS IS NOT ENABLED
    }
}
```